# Elementary argument for the characterization of morphisms between projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I'm dealing with Exercise 7.8 of Gathmann's 2021 notes of Algebraic Geometry. The exercise is:

> Show that every morphism $f\colon \mathbb{P}^n\to \mathbb{P}^m$ must be of the form
> $$ f\colon \mathbb{P}^n\to \mathbb{P}^m, x\mapsto (f_0(x):\cdots :f_m(x)) $$
> as in Lemma 7.4, i.e. with $f_0,\cdots,f_m\in K[x_0,\cdots, x_n]$ homogeneous polynomials of the same degree such that $V_p(f_0,\cdots, f_m)=\varnothing$.

Some friends told me that this can be shown using ''line bundle'', but I never learned that and there is nothing about that on Grathmann's notes near that exercise. There should be some elementary argument that would work.

I once thought that this can be shown by restricting to the affine coordinates as in [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557206/show-that-every-morphism-f-colon-mathbba1-setminus-0-to-mathbbp1-ca). This would work for $n=1$, thanks to that the open subsets in $\mathbb{A}^1$ are all principal, so that we have good global description for regular functions on them. However, for $n>1$, the open subsets in $\mathbb{A}^n$ would be wild and the regular functions only have local descriptions, so I doubt if it is the right way to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: It seems that every open subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is a finite union of principal ones would make the previous argument work for here. The argument seems tedious so I haven't thought about it carefully, but am I in the right way?

Comment: Hint: consider the induced morphism $\Bbb A^{n+1}\to\Bbb A^{m+1}$ and what must happen for this to actually give a map $\Bbb P^n\to\Bbb P^m$.

Comment: @KReiser Why would $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{P}^n\to \mathbb{P}^m$ factor through $\mathbb{A}^{m+1}$?

Comment: Ahh, I guess you're right, I'm assuming a little bit of what I want to prove there. You can definitely use the argument you list in your edit - it is indeed true that every open subset of $\Bbb A^n$ is a finite union of principal opens (this is a consequence of noetherianity, for instance - every subset is quasi-compact, so take the cover by principal opens; or take a finite generating set for the ideal of the complement of the open and consider the union of the principal opens corresponding to those generators).

Comment: @KReiser Yeah I know that it is true. But I'm a kind of not sure if that argument would work the problem out.